# Not able to buid with latest tag in dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-pull, docker-push

I m trying to build an image with two tags - latest and version number.

Current implementation-

```
docker build \
    -t ${IMAGE_NAME}:latest \
    -t ${IMAGE_NAME}:${VERSION} \
docker push "$IMAGE_NAME:latest"
docker push "$IMAGE_NAME:$VERSION"
```

Current output-
The push refers to repository [docker.artifactory.in.com/ci-imageatest]

```
[+] Building 0.1s (17/17) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                 
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                          
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:cf                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => naming to docker.artifactory.in.com/pysdk-ci-imageatest                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => naming to docker.artifactory.in.com/pysdk-ci-image:20220
```

Instead of creating a latest tag its creating repo ci-imageatest.

Can someone help what am I missing.

Comment: please also paste the **push** command.

Comment: @LeiYang added the push command

Comment: then paste full command output? remove the too long unnecessary parts.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
docker push ${IMAGE_NAME}:latest
```

Comment: do you mean you fixed by changing `"$IMAGE_NAME:latest"` to `${IMAGE_NAME}:latest`?